# Reading a binary file in Python into a struct

Tags: python, struct, binaryfiles

How do I go about opening a binary data file in Python and reading back the values one `long`
at a time, into a struct. I have something like this at the moment but I think this will keep overwriting `idList`, I want to append to it, so I end up with a tuple of all the `long` values in the file -

```
file = open(filename, "rb")
    try:
        bytes_read = file.read(struct.calcsize("=l"))
        while bytes_read:
            # Read 4 bytes(long integer)
            idList = struct.unpack("=l", bytes_read)
            bytes_read = file.read(struct.calcsize("=l"))
    finally:
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest (python 2.6 or better):

```
import array
idlist = array.array('l')
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        try: idlist.fromfile(f, 2000)
        except EOFError: break
idtuple = tuple(idlist)
```

Tuples are immutable, so they can't be built incrementally: so you have to build a different (mutable) sequence, then call `tuple` on it at the end.  If you don't actually *need* specifically a tuple, of course, you can save the last, costly step and keep the array or list or whatever.  Avoiding trampling over built-in names like `file` is advisable anyway;-).

If you *have* to use the `struct` module for a job that's best handled by the `array` module (e.g., because of a bet),

```
idlist = [ ]
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = f.read(struct.calcsize("=l"))
        if not bytes_read: break
        oneid = struct.unpack("=l", bytes_read)[0]
        idlist.append(oneid)
```

The `with` statement (also available in 2.5 with an import form the future) is better than the old try/finally in clarity and conciseness.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we're limited to using Python 2.5 at the moment, how would this differ in that?

Comment: @Adam, just add `from __future__ import with_statements` at the start of the module.

Comment: In the array example you call fromfile with a value of 2000, should that not be 4, for the four byte integer? Or am I misunderstanding this function?

Comment: @Adam, `.fromfile(f, N)` reads up to `N` items (raising `EOFError` if it's read less than `N` due to end-of-file, but you just need to catch that).  The `array` instance already knows that each item takes 4 bytes because it knows it's an array of `l`s, i.e., 4-byte signed ints.  Reading a few thousand items at a time (exact number doesn't matter, 2000 rather than 1000 or 3000 is just because you do have to pick an exact number;-) is more efficient than reading one at a time (not a huge difference in performance, but, "waste not, want not";-).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
idList = struct.unpack("=l", bytes_read)
```

to

```
idList.append(struct.unpack("=l", bytes_read)[0])
```